# Is there Nautilus 3.6.1 (deb) binary?

Tags: nautilus

I'm looking for Nautilus 3.6.1 deb package for ubuntu, and I wasn't able to compile it's source.

How can I compile Nautilus?

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus file manager is a project of Gnome.

Here are the files you want : http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/nautilus/

Comment: Yes,

I want to install it on my ubuntu, and I need a (deb) package.

Comment: You can create a .deb package if you want , or follow the instructions inside the REAMDE or INSTALL files to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code for Nautilus 3.6.1 from [here](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/nautilus/3.6/nautilus-3.6.1.tar.xz). A detailed description of how to build nautilus from source is given on [Nautilus homepage](https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Development/Nautilus).